# How to get certain element (using JavaScript) from HTML with similar classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, element, queryselector

How can I get one certain element from HTML using JavaScript.
I have this code.

```
<div class="Content"> 

 <div class="First Block">
  <div class="num">Text From First Block</div>
 </div>

 <div class="Second Block">
  <div class="num">Text From Second Block</div>
 </div>

 <div class="Third Block">
  <div class="num">Text Third Second Block</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

I want to write "Text From Second Block".
If I write this code

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.num').innerText);
```

I will get "Text From First Block"

Comment: Did you try document.querySelector('.Second Block .num') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using **queryselector** you can use **getElementsByClassName()** and instead of enter the index number of your tag

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("Block")[i].innerHTML)
```

Comment: instead of i** :in the explaination

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a few simple ways.

Use parent selector `.Second.Block`. Like this:

```
document.querySelector('.Second.Block > .num').innerText
```

Also, `querySelector()` allows you to specify pseudo-classes such as `:nth-child()`. Like this:

```
document.querySelector('.Block:nth-child(2) > .num').innerText
```

And use `querySelectorAll()`, referring as a **collection**, indicating the index in square brackets. Like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.num')[1].innerText
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".Second.Block > .num").innerText);
console.log(document.querySelector(".Block:nth-child(2) > .num").innerText);
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".num")[1].innerText);
```

```html
<div class="Content">
    <div class="First Block">
        <div class="num">Text From First Block</div>
    </div>

    <div class="Second Block">
        <div class="num">Text From Second Block</div>
    </div>

    <div class="Third Block">
        <div class="num">Text Third Second Block</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.querySelectorAll`

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".num")[1].innerText)
```

```html
<div class="Content"> 

 <div class="First Block">
  <div class="num">Text From First Block</div>
 </div>

 <div class="Second Block">
  <div class="num">Text From Second Block</div>
 </div>

 <div class="Third Block">
  <div class="num">Text Third Second Block</div>
 </div>

</div>
```